# ASP.NET error when connecting to AWS RDS Database

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-rds

I am going to try to keep this short and simple.

I have created a very simple asp.net website in visual studio 2010. I have a simple code on a particular page that connects to an amazon RDS database.

When i run this website on my local computer it runs fine pulling the data from the database. But when i put the files onto the microsoft webhost server through 1and1.com i get a whole slew of error messages.

my site [www.kellendenny.com/Default.aspx](http://www.kellendenny.com/Default.aspx) loads fine. if you got to [www.kellendenny.com/Styles/WebForm1.aspx](http://www.kellendenny.com/Styles/WebForm1.aspx) you should see the errors I am talking about.

I don't understand why the code will work on my local machine but not from the webhost.

Thank you for your time.

below is the code for the WebForm1.aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Styles.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" tagprefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Data</h2>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="4" /> 
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        Width="900px">
        <series>
            <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" XValueMember="DateTime" 
                YValueMembers="Voltage">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:Chart>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db2ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DateTime], [Voltage] FROM [Table1]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTime" HeaderText="DateTime" 
                SortExpression="DateTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Voltage" HeaderText="Voltage" 
                SortExpression="Voltage" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the code for the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="db2ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=testdevelopment.cwroskb2ogi8.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXXXX"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You shouldn't ask us to navigate to your site. Please include the code and any errors here, you will be much more likely to receive a good answer (or any answer at all) if you do.

Comment: What type of hosting package do you have ? Is it a dedicated server or shared hosting?

Comment: The hosting is 1and1 windows basic so its shared (http://www.1and1.com/windows-hosting)

Comment: I added the code for the Web.Config file (with database password redacted) as well as the WebForm1.aspx page.

Comment: I can not say for sure but I would guess that the hosting provider may be blocking -OR- require that a firewall rule be opened. Either true a support query or through the control panel of your site on 1and1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you are able to connect to AWS RDS from your local machine on your local network. This would indicate that your connection string is indeed correct.

As the issue occurs when the code is deployed I would think that the hosting provider may be blocking or require that a firewall rule be opened/applied. This can probably be achieved either true a support query or through the control panel of your site on 1and1.com

Comment: Thank you for responding. I ended up loading a free AWS EC2 windows server and installing the application there. I had much more control and was able to get it up and running just perfectly. I will probably look into amazon's services and transfer my domain over to the AWS solution and ditch 1and1.com

Comment: @ridonkulus No problem, glad to hear you have it sorted. Would you consider my answer as correct based on your question? Thanks

Comment: I would thank you! I have marked it as correct thank you for checking back.